# IIS7 - sending email

Tags: email, iis-7

i'm totally confused about configure asp.net website to send email - hope you can help me here please

it is running on Win 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5
i have VS 2010 asp.net application trying to send email.

[1] i got STMP server insatlled in this server - but unable to find "Send EMail" In Features View.. Is this an issue?

[2] this is my code

```
using System.Net.Mail;
:
:
//(1) Create the MailMessage instance
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("test@mycompany.com", "test222@mycompany.com");


//(2) Assign the MailMessage's properties
mm.Subject = "Subject";
mm.Body = "the content of body here";
mm.IsBodyHtml = true;

//(3) Create the SmtpClient object
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

//(4) Send the MailMessage (this will use the Web.config settings)
smtp.Send(mm);
```

web.config file has

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network
            host="MailServer2"
            port="25"
            userName="user_id"
            password="password"
          />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

in my company we have a mail server (MS Exchnage server) hosted on differnt server (say MailServer2)

so

if i use "host=" as MailServer2 (this is mail server) - it says, **"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused "**

if i use "host=" as local-host-ip - error is **"Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for "**

even i tried to config the SMTP using Start-->Admin toold-->IIS 6.0 Manager option, but no joy.

is i'm doing anything silly? iis7 is very new to me - any help is much appricated.

any help please?

Cheers
Venu

Comment: What version of Exchange Server?

Comment: i tried to find it using method specified here [link]http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/determine-the-version-of-microsoft-exchange-server-my-account-connects-to-HA010117038.aspx[/link] and it shows as 32981. but speaking to my admin guy he said it is 2007.


is this config depends on Exchange version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MailServer2, if there actually is a SMTP server running on that machine, it is probably on a different port.  The error message says the SMTP server isn't running on port 25.

When you point it at the local IP, this error message:

Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for "

Is actually coming from the SMTP server. Everything is working correctly.  Now, you just need to change the setting in your SMTP server to allow relay for localhost or your account (you don't say what SMTP server you are using, other than it's installed locally).

--hth,
Dave

Comment: Thanks. learnt that firewall was blocking the request from my server - and it started wokring after enabling the firewall port for my server. ! Thanks Dave for comment.